# PartitionStrategy with titanDb and DynamoDb as a backend not adding vertex to graph

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, titan

I'm having trouble working with PartitionStrategy and  titanDb and DynamoDb as a backend. I'm using dynamoDb as a local backend using dynamodb-titan-storage-backend plugin. Below is a simple test case I've written in java:

```
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanEdge;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanGraph;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanGraphQuery;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanTransaction;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanVertex;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversal;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.strategy.decoration.PartitionStrategy;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Direction;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;  
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TitanTest {

    TitanGraph titanGraph;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        BaseConfiguration conf = new BaseConfiguration();
        conf.setProperty("storage.backend", "com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager");
        conf.setProperty("storage.dynamodb.client.endpoint", "http://localhost:4567");
        titanGraph = TitanFactory.open(conf);
    }

   @Test
   public void testAddVertexToTitanGraph(){
       titanGraph.addVertex( "name", "Bob", "age", "4.6x10^9");
       titanGraph.traversal().V().forEachRemaining(it -> {
        System.out.println("Found " + it.value("name"));
       });
   }

    @Test
    public void addVertexViaPartitionStrategy() {
        PartitionStrategy partitionStrategy = PartitionStrategy.build().partitionKey("_partition").writePartition("a").addReadPartition("a").create();
        GraphTraversalSource graphTraversalSource = GraphTraversalSource.build().with(partitionStrategy).create(titanGraph);
        GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> marko = graphTraversalSource.addV("name", "marko", "age", 29);
        graphTraversalSource.V().forEachRemaining(it -> {
        System.out.println("name:" + it.value("name").toString());
        });

    }
}
```

However, I don't seem to get anything printed out when I run the addVertexViaPartitionStrategy test case. I've followed the example here:
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_partitionstrategy

I'm able to read and write to the database, see test testAddVertexToTitanGraph, just not able to create a vertex when using partition stratergy.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue with Titan 1.0.0 with a cassandra back-end. Apparently you have to fetch the result of the traversal in order for the Vertex to be added.

So this works:

```
    GraphTraversalSource gA = GraphTraversalSource.build().with(partitionStrategy).create(g);
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> addV = gA.addV();
    Vertex v = addV.next();
    System.out.println("v: " + v);

    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Long> count = gA.V().count();
    long amt = count.next();
    System.out.println("Partition vertex count: " + amt);
```